# No me sale seecontentview en android studio cuando creo una aplicación

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estoy intentando crear una aplicación en Android Studio versión 2022.3.1 y no me sale `seecontentview` Y quiero saber porque no me sale

Comment: Puedes agregar una imagen, puedes agregar la forma en la que crear un proyecto, el código de tu MainActivity. Hay que ser más específico